# Vim opens a new folder instead of an existing file with `set enc=utf-8` enabled

Tags: windows, utf-8, vim

When I open a file with vim or gvim from console on windows that is located in a sub directory (e.g. `gvim subdir/file`), it creates a new file at `subdir\subdir\file` saying `"subdir\file" [New DIRECTORY]` instead of simply opening the existing file at `subdir\file`.
[image: GVim directory issue]

This happens since I added the following line to my vimrc:

```
set enc=utf-8
```

Is there a possibility to open and create files in UTF-8 mode on Windows without this issue?
You may also look at [my vimrc file](https://gist.github.com/741879).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of the `autochdir` and `encoding` options in your vimrc. First set the `encoding` then `autochdir`

```
set enc=utf-8
set autochdir
```

An explanation can be found [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_use@googlegroups.com/msg11408.html)

Comment: This is the solution for my problem. Thank you very much!